# How can I log username in wso2 logs in case of failed attempt of a user in wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I wanted to log username, in case of a login failed scenario in the wso2 identity server using adaptive authentication

code snippet for adaptive authentication

```
    var abc = function(context) {
    executeStep(1, {
        onSuccess: function (context) {
            var user = context.currentKnownSubject;
            
                }
            }
        },
        onFail: function (context){
           
            var username = context.request.params.userame;
            var user = context.currentKnownSubject;
            //i have used these two approach but the username is coming as null

            
        }
    });
};
```

Could anyone please help with how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var user = context.currentKnownSubject;` or `var user = context.steps[1].subject` (change the authentication step inside [] as required) can be used to refer the **authenticated [user object](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/references/adaptive-authentication-js-api-reference/#user-object)** that represents the user details.
So, on the successful authentication step, you can get the authenticated user's username by
`context.steps[1].subject.username` or `context.currentKnownSubject.username`

Since there is no authenticated subject set on authentication failure, we can't access the user details from `context.currentKnownSubject` / `context.steps[1].subject` under onFail function.(Related issue: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/3950).

But you can retrieve the user input username as `context.request.params.username[0]` (NOTE: var username = context.request.params.userame; in your code has a typo; `userame`)

Try the following:

```
var onLoginRequest = function(context) {
    executeStep(1, {
        onSuccess: function (context) {
            Log.info('Username: ' + context.steps[1].subject.username);
            Log.info('Username: ' + context.currentKnownSubject.username);
        },
        onFail: function (context){
            Log.info('Username: ' + context.request.params.username[0]);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following.

```
Log.info('User ' + context.currentKnownSubject.identifier);
```

I would not recommend logging the username when you are in a production environment because it can reveal sensitive information about the user (if you are using the email as the username). Make sure to remove the logs (comment them) once you are in production.

You can find more information about adaptive auth in [here](https://I%20would%20not%20recommend%20logging%20the%20username%20when%20you%20are%20in%20a%20production%20environment%20because%20it%20can%20reveal%20sensitive%20information%20about%20the%20user%20(if%20you%20are%20using%20the%20email%20as%20the%20username).).